# Метод для поиска по разным столбцам

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

У меня есть `Form` с `ComboBox` и `TextBox`. Первый содержит имена столбцов, второй содержит текст для поиска. В качестве источника `ComboBox` берет `ListTypeSearch` из элементов `ItemSearch`. В обработке нажатия кнопки `Поиск` вызывается метод `Search()`.

Если дать имя столбца так, то ничего не найдется

```
EF.Functions.Like(item.Value, ...); // Value = "FullName"
```

Если указывать столбец из модели, поиск работает

```
EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, ...);
```

Можно ли в рамках одного метода `Search()` подменять столбец по которому должен идти поиск?

```
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "FullName", Display = "ФИО" });
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "PassportSeries", Display = "Серия" });
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "PassportNumber", Display = "Номер" });

public class ItemSearch
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

internal List<WorkerTableRow> Search(ItemSearch item, string text)
{
    try
    {
        Found = new List<WorkerTableRow>();
        using (ModelContext model = new ModelContext())
        {
            Found = (from w in model.Workers
                     where EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, // этот код
                                             String.Format("%{0}%", text))
                     select new WorkerTableRow
                     {
                         ...
                     })
                     .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... }

    return Found;
}
```

**Update**

Сделал следующим образом. Это можно упростить? Может `C#` умеет сам возвращать свойства по имени.

```
where EF.Functions.Like(w.GetProperty(item.Value), 
                        String.Format("%{0}%", text))


public partial class Workers
{
    ...

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string PassportSeries { get; set; }
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }

    public string GetProperty(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "FullName":
                return FullName;
            case "PassportSeries":
                return PassportSeries;
            case "PassportNumber":
                return PassportNumber;
            default:
                return string.Empty;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот метод работает?

Comment: @Ruslan_K да, через `GetProperty()` работает

Comment: Ваш запрос с `GetProperty` хоть и рабочий, но получается неэффективный: фильтрация будет происходить на _клиенте_, а не на _сервере_.

Comment: Как фильтрация по базе может отказаться на клиенте?
Впринципе в C# можно получить свойство по строке через рефлексию, в стиле 
`w.GetType().GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(w, null);`

Comment: @DmitryDavydov - запрос с `GetProperty` не может быть транслирован в sql. В итоге получается sql-запрос совсем без `where`. Из базы вытягивается _вся_ таблица, а `where` выполняется уже на клиенте. EF Core тем и "славится", что норовит вытянуть всю БД. Обычный EF скорее выбросил бы исключение.

Comment: Можно попробовать Dynamic LINQ. Но я не знаю, работает ли эта библиотека с EF Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я включил логирование запросов и посмотрел, что генерируется в том и другом случае.

Если использовать `Like(w.FullName, ...)`, то получается следующий запрос:

```
Executed DbCommand (94ms) [Parameters=[@__Format_1='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [w].[WorkerId], [w].[FullName], [w].[PassportNumber], [w].[PassportSeries]
FROM [Workers] AS [w]
WHERE [w].[FullName] LIKE @__Format_1
```

Видно, что в `WHERE` используется `LIKE` и передаётся параметр.

---

Если использовать `Like(w.GetProperty(item.Value), ...)`, то получается следующее:

> The LINQ expression 'where __Functions_0.Like([w].GetProperty(__item_1), __Format_2)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

```
Executed DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [w].[WorkerId], [w].[FullName], [w].[PassportNumber], [w].[PassportSeries]
FROM [Workers] AS [w]
```

Во-первых, выдаётся предупреждение, что метод `GetProperty` не может быть транслирован в sql и будет выполнен локально.

Во-вторых, в самом запросе отсутствует `WHERE` и нет параметров.

---

Вообще, EF Core известен тем, что по умолчанию выполняет на клиенте те действия, которые не может транслировать в sql на сервере. Это может приводить к вытягиванию большого объёма данных и снижения производительности.

[Breaking changes included in EF Core 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) - в этой статье написано, что в EF Core 3 поведение изменится и станет таким же, как в обычном EF: если запрос не может быть транслирован в действия на сервере, то будет выброшено исключение. А если кому-то всё же нужно продолжить выполнение linq-запроса локально, всегда можно вызвать `AsEnumerable()`.

---

Решение:

```
List<WorkerTableRow> Search(ItemSearch item, string text)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("%{0}%", text);

    using (var model = new ModelContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Worker> query = model.Workers;

        if (item.Value == "FullName")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, pattern));

        if (item.Value == "PassportSeries")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.PassportSeries, pattern));

        if (item.Value == "PassportNumber")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.PassportNumber, pattern));

        return query.Select(w => new WorkerTableRow { ... }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант `item.Value` один на вызов, можно `if-else`. Если через `GetType().GetProperty()` запрос выйдет как с исключением?

Comment: @Owl - _GetType().GetProperty()_ - нет, в Sql Server отсутствуют такие функции, поэтому этот код невозможно транслировать в sql. Поэтому, если запрос с ними и будет работать, то опять-таки на клиенте.

Comment: Если я добавлю после условий строку `int count = query.Count();` и сделаю `.Select.OrderBy(q => q.Id).Skip(Page * Size).Take(Size)` с целью вывода результатов поиска по страницам. Где будет выполнен запрос `Count()`? Если он заставит загружать все результаты,то постраничный вывод становиться бессмысленным.

Comment: @Owl - `query.Count()` будет выполнен на сервере, _отдельным_ запросом. `query...Select...Order...ToList()` - тоже на сервере, _другим_ запросом. Итого _два_ запроса, но оба на сервере. А вообще, задавайте такое новым вопросом, а не в комментарии.

Comment: @Owl - освойте просмотр сгенерированных запросов. Тогда сами сможете узнавать, что там и как. Про логирование тоже следует создать новую тему.

Comment: @Owl - [как сделать логирование запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005530/184217)